# Dynamic layout for mobile visitors on ASP.NET MVC 3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, mobile, viewengine, wurfl

I want to dynamically change the layout, based on whether the user is accessing the site from a mobile device or not. I have a few questions on the subject.

1. I would like to change the layout once it's determined, but before the view is rendered. That is, is there some hook I can use where I can change `layout.cshtml` to `layout.mobile.cshtml` "recursively" for any nested layouts that there might be.

   Is overriding `RazorViewEngine`'s `CreateView` method enough? It takes a `masterPath` parameter, so maybe I could implement a custom `RazorViewEngine` and override this method, right?
2. The second question would be regarding mobile browser detection. I don't really care that much about specific devices. I just want to differentiate desktop from mobile. Is something like `WURFL` a necessity in this case?

   Is checking something like `Request.Browser.ScreenPixelsWidth` and `ScreenPixelsHeigth` ridiculous? (since most I'd be changing would be using or not `jQuery.mobile` and it's data-attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This functionality is built-into ASP.NET MVC 4 so you get it out-of-the-box.

Scott Hansleman [blogged](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NuGetPackageOfTheWeek10NewMobileViewEnginesForASPNETMVC3SpeccompatibleWithASPNETMVC4.aspx) about how you could achieve the same in ASP.NET MVC 3 and be ready for the upgrade because the NuGet he suggested is spec-compatible with ASP.NET MVC 4.

Answer (score 0):

If you can, use ASP MVC 4 as Darin Dimitrov pointed out. It supports this out of the box.

If you are stuck on MVC 3, here's how we do it in our product:

1) Install WURFL

2) Implement an HttpCapabilitiesProvider which calls WURFL and resolves device capabilities; stuff resolved caps into the result. Be sure to add a property called isMobileBrowser (wurfl exposes this)

3) Tell .NET to use your capabilities provider instead of default HttpCapabilitiesBase.BrowserCapabilitiesProvider = new YourBrowserCapabilitiesProvider(_wurflManager);

4) Create a CustomViewEngine (inherit RazorViewEngine). Override FindPartialView & FindView. These should look at controllerContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.Browser.Capabilities["isMobileBrowser"] and map to appropriate name, eg myView.cshtml.mobile.  You need to resolve both viewName and masterName.

4.1) Still in CustomViewEngine's FindPartialView & FindView, search search ~/Views/{0}/{1}  and ~/Views/Shared/{0}/{1} where {0} is the controller (controllerContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("controller")) and {1} is your mapped view name

4.2) Return return new ViewEngineResult(CreateView(controllerContext, viewPath, masterPath), this);